# Cronjob not ending when deleting files

Tags: linux, cron, redhat, delete-file

When my cronjob runs it doesn't appear to end. Its a simple job to delete some files every 2 days. The job wont end and it deletes the file but will not release the space without a reboot. Now the machine has no free storage unless it is rebooted. Has anyone else experienced this and if so how did you fix/resolve it?

```
0 23 */2 * * /usr/bin/find "var/log/" -name "messages*" -delete
```

Here is my cronjob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that the files are used by some other process. In Unix, when you delete the file, the inode and the space are not reclaimed as long as some process has still a file descriptor open on it.

You can easily find which are the process holding it using `lsof /var/log`

Comment: I have looked at the open files and there is nothing present from /var/logs.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a file  will `unlink` the file from the file system's directory structure but if the file is still open (in use by a running process) it will still be accessible to this process and will continue to occupy space on disk, so these processes may need to be restarted before that file's space will be cleared up on the file-system

You can obtain the PIDs of the process that are using the files: `lsof | grep deleted` .

You can check which file are open by a certain process using his PID by: `ls -l /proc/PID/fd`

Also you can check the locked files on your machine: `lslocks` (`cat /proc/locks` more details).